# React call a function from another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js

after setup a simple image upload i've tried to call another function from a function and the logs spits out

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): self.sendImage is not a function

[image: logs]

**here is the code**

```
  readFile(files) {
        var self = this;
    if (files && files[0]) {
      let formPayLoad = new FormData();
      formPayLoad.append("attachment_image", files[0]);
      self.sendImage(formPayLoad);
    }

  }

  sendImage(formPayLoad) {
    let auth_token = window.localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
    fetch("/posts", {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Access: auth_token
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: formPayLoad
    })
      .then(response => response.json())

  }
```

To fix it i've tried to change the variable this to self and still persist the error.

so, please, can someone clarify why this Unhandles Rejecton?
is related to class Es6?

Comment: Did you bind `sendImage` in the constructor?

Comment: Is this code part of a class? And how is `readFile` called?

Comment: @AndrewL nope, i must?

Comment: @trincot i think yes, and is called from dropzone   onDrop={this.readFile}

Comment: The problem is that dropzone will call `readFile` without `this` set to your object. See the duplicate reference to read all about `this`. There are several solutions. One is to do  `onDrop={this.readFile.bind(this)}` or `onDrop={() => this.readFile()}`

Comment: @trincot, ok thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may need to bind the function inside the constructor ex

`this.sendImage = this.sendImage.bind(this);`

or you can use ES6 and use an arrow function to eliminate the need for an arrow function

```
sendImage = (formPayLoad) => {
    let auth_token = window.localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
    fetch("/posts", {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Access: auth_token
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: formPayLoad
    })
      .then(response => response.json())

  }
```

Comment: thank you i gonna check

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if it helps!

Comment: Jacob Bralish thank you worked!